# blazor (server side) javascript interop: Javascript fails because code must run as user-initiated

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am running into a problem writing data into the clipboard using server-side blazor.
The library https://github.com/lgarron/clipboard-polyfill fails to write a text to clipboard after a button press using server-side blazor under firefox V69, but is works under chrome V77.

With a plain old javascript html page without blazor the clipboard write works in firefox and chrome.

I assume that firefox has the security requirement that clipboard manipulation must happen in code flagged as "user-initiated".

Because server-side blazor goes from user-initiated javascript to server side c# to websocket-event javascript the "copy to clipboard" javascript code is not flagged as "user-initiated" anymore.

Is there a official way or hack in blazor to execute javascript interop code with the "user-initiated" flag on?

Update: Added a repository for simple reproduction https://github.com/Henk7/BlazorJSUserInitiatedPermission

Update 2:
Issue: Is now tracked at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15109

Comment: No fix available from me, but I found this for context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard